# How to deprecate an argument?

Tags: r

Is there a standard way of deprecating arguments in R?

Example: For a web API package, I previously included a `paging=TRUE` argument which would paginate over all the results and download everything.

Now I want to have a `limit` argument instead, and only download everything if set to `limit=0`. This effectively eliminates the need for the `paging` argument, so I need to let people now it basically does nothing now. How do I do that?

Comment: You could follow the example of the lme4 authors. They have now three parameters that might be deprecated some day because they kept renaming a parameter: http://search.r-project.org/R/library/lme4/html/predict.merMod.html

Comment: To be more clear, set `limit = if(paging) 0 else theDefault` and say in the documentation that the `paging` parameter shouldn't be used. You could also provide a `warning` or `message` if you feel strongly about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like as follows maybe would do for you?

```
foo <- function(paging = T, limit = 0) {
  if (!missing("paging"))
    warning("argument deprecated")
}
```

Example outputs:

```
# > foo()
# > foo(limit = 0)
# > foo(T)
# Warning message:
#   In foo(T) : argument deprecated
# > foo(paging = T)
# Warning message:
#   In foo(paging = T) : argument deprecated
```

As @Roland points out, it should also be mentioned in the documentation for that function that the argument is now deprecated.

Comment: Do not use `print` for messages. It can't be surpressed by the user.

Answer (score 7):

I found this discussion when looking for a solution to rename a function argument for a function of a package. This is not exactly an answer to your question, but very familiar, and I thought maybe the solution is helpful for others as well.

So, to rename an argument of a function without harming existing function calls, I came up with the following solution, based on the answer from @John Smith.

The functionality of `old_arg` remains for deprecated function calls of `foo` and is ignored for function calls of the new version of `foo`.

```
# old version
foo <- function(x, y, old_arg = c("a", "b", "c")){

   old_arg <- match.arg(old_arg, c("a", "b", "c"))

   if(old_arg == "a"){
      return(x*y)
   }else if(old_arg == "b"){
      return(x+y)
   }else if(old_arg == "c"){
      return(x-y)
   }
}

# new version
foo <- function(x, y, new_arg = c("a", "b", "c"), old_arg = c("a", "b", "c")){

   if (!missing("old_arg")){
      warning("Argument deprecated, use new_arg instead. 
              The parameter new_arg is set equal the parameter old_arg.")
      new_arg <- old_arg
   }

   new_arg <- match.arg(new_arg, c("a", "b", "c"))
   if(new_arg == "a"){
      return(x*y)
   }else if(new_arg == "b"){
      return(x+y)
   }else if(new_arg == "c"){
      return(x-y)
   }
}
```

Comment: I do think it is helpful. In fact, I ended up doing something similar to this. I'm not going to change the accepted answer because it was a while ago, but I think people will find the worked out example quite useful.