# How can I process arguments of parent function?

Tags: r

I have some deprecated arguments to functions in an R package. I do something like this:

```
foo <- function(x, y, newarg , oldarg ){

   if (!missing("oldarg")){
      warning("Argument deprecated, use newarg instead. 
              The parameter newarg is set equal the parameter oldarg.")
      newarg <- oldarg
   }

 ### Then the actual function code....
}
```

which is being discussed here: [How to deprecate an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906200/how-to-deprecate-an-argument)

I'd like to align how this is handled across the package by using a function for it like:

```
foo <- function(arg1,newarg,oldarg){

newarg <- myDeprecFun(oldarg,newarg)

 ### Then the actual function code....

}
```

Now I am hitting a wall. I have read through http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html and other chapters of the book but I still don't get it. I tried a wrapper like this:

```
myDeprecFun <- deprecatedArg <- function(oldarg,newarg){
    
    args <- callArgs(-2)
    names.args <- names(args)
    
### things like
    if( oldarg %in% names.args ) {
        message(sprintf("%s is a deprecated argument. Please use %s instead.",oldarg,newarg))
        return(args[[oldarg]])
    }
    
### return newarg
    parent.frame()[[newarg]]

}
```

where callArgs is:

```
callArgs <- function(which=-1){
    
### args in call.
    ## no args are needed for this
    args.call <- as.list(
        match.call(
            definition = sys.function(which=which),
            call = sys.call(which=which)
        )
    )[-1]
    
## get the argument contents
    argsconts <- lapply(args.call, eval, envir = parent.frame(n=-which+1))
    
    as.list(do.call(c,argsconts))
}
```

One problem is the number of environments I should jump in the `eval` call in callArgs. I am very confused about that. If easier, it would be fine by me passing the environment in which myDeprecFun() is called as an argument to myDeprecFun() and then to callArgs().

Another problem is I'm not sure callArgs() will capture all arguments. What if some are not named in the function call, like

```
foo(a=1,3,4)
```

Here, argument 2 or 3 could be a deprecated argument.

Any hint to how I can construct such a function is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the call to `myDeprecFun`:

```
foo <- function(arg1,newarg,oldarg){
  
  newarg <- myDeprecFun("oldarg", "newarg", match.call())
  newarg
}

myDeprecFun <- function(oldarg,newarg, thecall) {
  if (oldarg %in% names(thecall)) {
    message(sprintf("%s is a deprecated argument. Please use %s instead.",
                    oldarg,newarg))
    if (newarg %in% names(thecall)) {
      thecall[[newarg]]
    } else {
      thecall[[oldarg]]
    }
  } else {
    thecall[[newarg]]
  }
}

foo(a=1,3,4)
#oldarg is a deprecated argument. Please use newarg instead.
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland . I still need to understand how to use match.call() to get exactly what I need.

Comment: I created this question to clarify. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466813/how-to-get-a-named-list-of-all-provided-argument-values