# How to get a named list of all provided argument _values_?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function foo() to use inside another function bar() to get access to a named list of all argument values provided to bar().

I have tried to use this:
[getting the arguments of a parent function in R, with names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256834/getting-the-arguments-of-a-parent-function-in-r-with-names)

I think that question is similar but I can't make it work. Including @hadley 's suggestion, this is

```r
get_Args <- function(which=1){
    cl <- sys.call(-which)
    ## f1 <- get(as.character(cl[[1]]), mode="function", sys.frame(-which-1))
    ## accordng to Hadley, this is "better"
    f1 <- eval(cl[[1]], parent.frame(which))
    cl <- match.call(definition=f1, call=cl)
    as.list(cl)[-1]
}
```

Now use it in a function:

```r
fun1 <- function(a=1,b=2){
        getArgs()
    }
```

These work:

```r
    fun1(a=1,b=2)
    fun1(b=2)
    fun1(a=1)
```

But this one returns list(b=`bb`)

```r
bb=3
 fun1(b=bb)
```

I need that to return 3.

Comment: I think that you should avoid using `which` as argument name. `?which` is an R function that is used alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap out the name of the matched call (i.e. its first element) for `quote(list)`. Then `eval` that call in the correct frame:

```r
getArgs <- function(which = 1) {
  cl <- sys.call(-which)
  f1 <- eval(cl[[1]], parent.frame(which))
  cl <- match.call(definition = f1, call = cl)
  cl[[1]] <- quote(list)
  eval(cl, parent.frame(which))
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
fun1 <- function(a = 1, b = 2) {
  getArgs()
}

bb <- 3

fun1(b = bb)
#> $b
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Allan! I know this does what I asked about. What I forgot to emphasize beyond the title is I need a _named_ list. With your suggestion, this one returns an unnamed list:
fun1(bb)
I need that to return list(a=bb), just like fun1 reads it. Can you help with that too?

Comment: @JohnDoe see my update - it just uses the same method on your original function

Comment: Thank you again! I am sorry for not realizing how complicated this is. I am almost there. But it doesn't work inside function calls with "...". See this test: fun.bar1 <- function(a,...){
            fun1(a,...)
};

fun.bar1(a=1,b=2); I need list(a=1,b=2) back but I get "Error in match.call(definition = f1, call = cl) : 
  ... used in a situation where it does not exist". The issue is in sys.call() which does not expand the dots. I have looked at the manual and searched google but I can't figure out how to get sys.call() to do that. Can you also help with that?

Comment: I ended up replacing "which" with "which+1" in both eval lines, and it all worked. I am still processing to understand all the details here. Well, I still have a lot to learn about R.